# Set up virtual machine without installing all settings

Tags: virtual-machine

I am currently working on a group project and heared of a way to quickly generate a virtual machine with different programs pre installed such as eclipse, android studio possibly apache and tomcat. I think the VM generator uses script but I am not sure. I am tiered of recreating VM all the times and setting up different programs on them.

Can someone give me a good and easy VM generator?
I am looking for something that will minimize the human factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you're looking for is [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) I'd imagine.

Generally my approach for this is to find a good base box (I use the Debian boxes from BoxCutter) and then provide a provisioning shell script to install the various packages/configure things.

Both the vagrantfile and the provisioning script are committed to the repo so other contributors can use it with a simple `vagrant up`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was Packer used with Bento

https://www.packer.io/ 
https://www.bento.io/